# Qual a melhor maneira de agrupar objetos em SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

Se eu tenho por exemplo 3 shapes diferentes em SFML, e eu quero rotacionar todos em relação a um centro único, como se estes 3 shapes estivessem dentro de um quadrado, qual seria a melhor forma?
Seria deixando-os dentro de uma view e rotacionando a view?
Ou existe alguma forma mais prática?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente, por tudo que eu vi, a maneira mais simples e intuitiva é colocar os objetos dentro da visão.

Por exemplo:

```
  RectangleShape background (Vector2f(windowWidth, windowHeight)); // draw a full rectangle to show the container dimensions
    background.setFillColor(Color::White);

    RectangleShape r1 (Vector2f(100,100)); // 1st object
    r1.setFillColor(Color::Red);
    r1.setPosition(Vector2f(30,10));


    RectangleShape r2 (Vector2f(150,200)); // 2nd object
    r2.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
    r2.setPosition(Vector2f(120,160));


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.setView(view);
        window.draw(background);
        window.draw(r1);
        window.draw(r2);
        view.setRotation(30); // affects all elements

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here is result]